# Variance Calculation Issue

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance

I want to calculate variance for the given problem , i am confused when to use n or n-1 , if nothing is mentioned.

also, what should i use in this case. please explain

[image: Question attached]

Comment: can you please explain in this case.

Comment: If you have $n$ observations in your data, what is the formula of variance?

Comment: sigma squared equals the sum of x minus the mean squared divided by n.

Comment: Yes, so if this question is in a plain descriptive statistics context, that is how you find the variance.

Comment: In all but a few textbooks, the  SD of a sample of size $n$ is defined as $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2.$ If you have $N$ items in a population with values $X_i$ then the population variance is $\sigma^2= \frac 1 N \sum_{i=1}^N (X_i - \mu)^2,$ where $\mu$ is the population mean.